# Implement a abort query button

Tags: c#, teradata, abort

I have written an application program in C# where i am connecting to Teradata DB and running a query entered by a user. Many a times this query is a big one and takes time to execute. 
I want to implement a cancel button on the main UI. If the user thinks that one query is taking too long to run, he should be able to abort that query. The queries will be select queries only. Right now, when a query is submitted, the UI freezes and the user has to abort the process to kill his query.
Thanks !
Samir Singh

Comment: I am a newbie to C# as i am a Teradata person. If anyone can share the code, it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute the query on a different thread  and not the UI Threat. Once the query results are available then show the results in UI , this will not freeze the UI .

Async-await is your friend in this scenario . Regarding the cancellation in sql I know you can do sqlcommand.cancel , check what the teradata provider provides and call that .

Answer (score 1):

Either do the Repaint on Application.ProcessMessage() or thread your app so that your DB calls can go out and perform thier stuff, while instructing the UI to do something nice.